# Custom post types columns strange issue

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 4 custom post types in my theme. When I add a description column (the_excerpt) for them I get some really strange behavior.

The description column repeats 4 times on each post on every custom post type. Also get a PHP notice that I can't get rid of.

Like this:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in H:\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mytheme\admin_includes\other\excerpt.php on line 10
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in H:\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mytheme\admin_includes\other\excerpt.php on line 10
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in H:\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mytheme\admin_includes\other\excerpt.php on line 10
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in H:\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mytheme\admin_includes\other\excerpt.php on line 10
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Here's my code for the custom post type. The code is the same for each one apart from the post type name.

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'testimonials_register');
    function testimonials_register() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Testimonials', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Testimonial', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Testimonial'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Testimonial'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Testimonial'),
            'new_item' => __('New Testimonial'),
            'view_item' => __('View Testimonial'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Testimonials'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/icons/testimonials-admin.png',
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'testimonials',
                'with_front' => FALSE,
            ),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        );
        register_post_type( 'testimonials' , $args );
    }

    add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "testimonials_custom_columns");
    add_filter("manage_edit-testimonials_columns", "testimonials_edit_columns");

    function testimonials_edit_columns($columns){
        $columns = array(
            "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
            "title" => "Testimonial Title",
            "description" => "Description"
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function testimonials_custom_columns($column){
        global $post;
        switch ($column)
        {
            case "description":
                the_excerpt();
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

I can't see why the description column would repeat for as many times as I have custom post types. Also I really can't figure out the PHP notice.

I'm developing locally on LAMP server and my WP version is 3.3.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Please ignore the PHP notice, that was caused by a custom excerpt function I had. Sorry about that! The description column still repeats 4 times though.

Comment: could you give the line of code that the error is describing?

Comment: You're redefining the columns array in the `testimonials_edit_columns` function instead of adding to it, is that intentional?

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond
 The error is gone now. It was just a missing global post. The main issue still remains though that the_excerpt is repeated 4 times for each post in the description column.

Comment: @t31os thanks for the comment. I've just copied that from a tutorial. How would you suggest I do it instead?

Answer (score 3):

Worked it out! Since WP version 3.1 the hook for adding columns to custom post types has changed.

Before 3.1 it was:

```
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "testimonials_custom_columns");
```

After 3.1 you have to use this:

```
add_action("manage_testimonials_posts_custom_column",  "testimonials_custom_columns");
```

So you have to specify the custom post type name in the manage_post_custom_column hook.

Hopefully this answer will save someone some time.